# sql - select multiple maximum values on a order by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have `date`, `work`, `Tasks` in a table. per every `date` we have multiple entries one entry per `Task`. On a given day if there are 3 tasks, we will have 3 entries

I want to take latests tasks per every work.
the below query gave me all the

```
SELECT task
FROM TEST_RESULTS 
WHERE RESULT ='PASSED' and
      task NOT IN (' ', 'N/A' )
ORDER BY work, date DESC  ;
```

I could get only list sorted. can someone help me in getting the rows with latest date per work.

sample output needed:

```
+ -----+-------+------------+
| work | task  | date       |
+ -----+-------+------------+
| 1    | clean | 1-jan-2018 |
| 1    | brush | 1-jan-2018 |
| 2    | wash  | 2-jan-2018 |
| 2    | clean | 2-jan-2018 |
| 3    | xyz   | 1-jan-2018 |
| 3    | ccc   | 1-jan-2018 |
+ -----+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

use `row_numner()` analytic function

```
select work,date
    from 
    (
    select work,date,row_number()over(partition by work order by date desc ) rn
    from  TEST_RESULTS 
    WHERE RESULT ='PASSED' and task NOT IN (' ','N/A' )
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

if you need just latest date all task then use simple subquery

```
with cte as 

(
select * ,max(date) over(partition by work) as mxdate
from TEST_RESULTS
where RESULT ='PASSED' and task NOT IN (' ','N/A' )
)  select * from cte where  
   date=mxdate
```

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: Its giving me only one task per work. I need all tasks with latest date.

Comment: @sitaramchikkala share sample data and it output on question

Comment: @sitaram chikkala: You want to show multiple tasks in case of ties. Simply replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` to achieve this.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that would be giving me "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @sitaram chikkala: This doesn't seem to make sense. You are saying that the query runs with `ROW_NUMBER`, but when you replace that with `RANK` it doesn't? That would be a serious flaw in the DBMS. You must have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest task per work, you want one result row per work, so you'd `GROUP BY work`. You can get the latest task with Oracle's `KEEP LAST`.

```
SELECT work, MAX(task) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date) AS last_task
FROM test_results 
WHERE result = 'PASSED' 
AND task NOT IN (' ', 'N/A')
GROUP BY work
ORDER BY work;
```

Comment: i need multiple tasks per day

Comment: @sitaram chikkala: In case of ties `KEEP LAST` picks one row (as does the approach with `ROW_NUMBER`). See my comment to Zaynul Abadin Tuhin's answer. You can use their query and change `ROW_NUMBER` to `RANK`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the task, you can use aggregation with `keep` in Oracle:

```
SELECT work,
       MAX(task) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date DESC) as most_recent_task,
       MAX(date)
FROM TEST_RESULTS 
WHERE RESULT = 'PASSED' and
      task NOT IN (' ', 'N/A' )
GROUP BY work;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_results ( work, task, "date", result ) AS
SELECT 1, 'clean', DATE '2018-01-01', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'brush', DATE '2018-01-01', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'wash',  DATE '2018-01-01', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicate with older date
SELECT 2, 'wash',  DATE '2018-01-02', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'clean', DATE '2018-01-02', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'brush', DATE '2018-01-01', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Not the latest date
SELECT 3, 'xyz',   DATE '2018-01-01', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'ccc',   DATE '2018-01-01', 'PASSED' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**: If you want the latest `date` for each `work`/`task` pair then:

```
SELECT work,
       task,
       MAX( "date" ) AS "date"
FROM   TEST_RESULTS 
WHERE  RESULT ='PASSED'
AND    task NOT IN (' ', 'N/A' )
GROUP BY work, task
ORDER BY work, "date" DESC;
```

**Output**:

```
WORK | TASK  | date     
---: | :---- | :--------
   1 | brush | 01-JAN-18
   1 | clean | 01-JAN-18
   2 | wash  | 02-JAN-18
   2 | clean | 02-JAN-18
   2 | brush | 01-JAN-18
   3 | xyz   | 01-JAN-18
   3 | ccc   | 01-JAN-18
```

**Query 2**: If you want the `task`s only for the latest `date` for each `work` then:

```
SELECT work,
       task,
       "date"
FROM   (
  SELECT work,
         task,
         "date",
         MAX( "date" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY work ) AS latest_date
  FROM   TEST_RESULTS 
  WHERE  RESULT ='PASSED'
  AND    task NOT IN (' ', 'N/A' )
)
WHERE  "date" = latest_date
ORDER BY work, task;
```

**Output**:

```
WORK | TASK  | date     
---: | :---- | :--------
   1 | brush | 01-JAN-18
   1 | clean | 01-JAN-18
   2 | clean | 02-JAN-18
   2 | wash  | 02-JAN-18
   3 | ccc   | 01-JAN-18
   3 | xyz   | 01-JAN-18
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ca8532de81570d18c1d374b106dfde5)*